# comparing array of chars to database records and read the record

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I trying to change database from MySQL to SQL server 2008 express for this VS2010 C# project. However after i change the connection string and queries, the program produces error 'null reference exception was unhandled' on the "cmr.close()". Here is the code and the place where the error occurred :

```
namespace JawiRdrSQL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=firstDB;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader cmr;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        //string sc;
        string strValue;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            strValue = textBox1.Text;


             char[] strVal = strValue.ToCharArray();
             Array.Reverse(strVal);

            foreach(char obj in strVal)
            {
                try
                {
                   sc.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand ("select JawiReader (stringR)" + ((char)obj), sc);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (cmr.Read())
                    {
                        label1.Content += cmr["stringJ"].ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("tidak sah");
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                cmr.Close(); // error occurs here
                sc.Close();
            }
        }
```

I am trying to produce a program that received a string which will be break into char and then compared to values in database. After that the program will output a string of values from the database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: if(cmr != null)cmr.Close();  The is no need to open and close the connetion for each command.  Move the connection 'sc' open/close outside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

Since you define it as;

```
SqlDataReader cmr;
```

it will be `null` by default. That's why you get `NullReferenceException` when you try to call;

```
cmr.Close();
```

because you never initialize your reader. You don't need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` for that case. Just generate your `cmr` with `ExecuteReader` method like;

```
cmd = new SqlCommand ("select JawiReader (stringR)" + ((char)obj), sc);
cmr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And please use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections, commands and reader.

Comment: thanks for the help. The error is gone now, however the program still have another error which is "an expression of non-boolean type specified in the context where a condition is expected, near stringr"

Comment: @jenan Are you sure your query is correct? Did you try it on management studio?

Comment: hi, sorry to ask you another question, but I already reach my limit for asking questions. I got a problem in displaying the sql content on my label. its suppose to display an array of char, so far I got an alert prompt saying "invalid column name on last char", do you know whats the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize your `SQLDataReader cmr;`

Therefore, of course you get an error when you want to close it.

**You cannot close an object which has not been created at all.**

*[I want to close the door of my castle, but unfortuntaley, this castle exists only in my dream ...]*